# What is the purpose of Whiskey rocks?

Tags: alcohol

My friend puts cold rocks in his whiskey to cool it down.  Is it to look fancy?

Can he just put the bottle in the fridge to cool it down without needing to put rocks in it?

Comment: Cooling the whole bottle is possible but it takes more time, space in the fridge or freezer and it does not work when you have several bottles to choose from. That's why you would usually use ice cubes and that's what rocks are designed to replace.

Comment: Related: [How do whisky stones keep your drink cold?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63164/59991)

Comment: Another option is to just leave a few whiskey glasses in the freezer.  This question would be a better fit on alcohol.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is to cool it down without dilluting it - ice cubes would melt.
And yes, you could simply cool the entire bottle, but it wouldn't look that fancy.

---

Note that some purists would wrinkle their noses and insist that whisky<sup>1</sup> is best enjoyed at room temperature and perhaps with a small dash of spring water.

<sup>1</sup> And I'm soooo not going into a whisky vs. whiskey debate here.

Comment: Just spell it "whiskyey" to please everyone.

Comment: `...some purists would wrinkle their noses and insist that whisky is best enjoyed at room temperature`.  No.  **All** purists would insist this.  That's part of what makes one a purist. ;)

Comment: then how come they sell the rocks, is it because of roger rabbit?

Comment: @Neil because people like your friend are willing to pay for them?

Comment: So you're saying if people stopped selling it then no one would go find regular granite rocks for free and put them in their drinks?

Comment: @Neil, see "Conclusion" [here](http://coolmaterial.com/feature/we-tested-a-bunch-of-whiskey-stones-to-see-which-were-the-best/). Some probably would, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: http://whiskyadvocate.com/2012/04/11/whisky-stones-do-they-rock-or-not/

Comment: If you go to a pub in Scotland and ask for a whiskey with ice you will get stern looks. Personally I think it depends on the whiskey whether ice is good or not. I have tried using rocks instead but they don't cool it down that much.

Answer (score 3):

The usual usage involves storing them in the freezer (much colder than the refrigerator) and using them instead of ice to cool your drink. When you use ice, you water down the liquor, which some people do not like. If you want the drink cold but not watered down, something like a whiskey stone is a good option.

Another thing is that they apparently cool the whiskey but not to the same degree that ice would, so you can taste more of the range of flavors. In fact, some people don't think they do a sufficient job of cooling at all.

As to storing the whiskey in the fridge, some people like their whiskey warm, so storing it in the fridge isn't necessarily a solution - it's much easier and faster to cool booze than to warm it up.